# Use existing SparkSession in POST/batches request

Tags: livy

I'm trying to use `Livy` to remotely submit several `Spark` *jobs*. Lets say I want to perform following **`spark-submit` task remotely** (with all the options as-such)

```
spark-submit \
--class com.company.drivers.JumboBatchPipelineDriver \
--conf spark.driver.cores=1 \
--conf spark.driver.memory=1g \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
--conf spark.serializer='org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions= -XX:+UseG1GC" \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
/home/hadoop/y2k-shubham/jars/jumbo-batch.jar \
\
--start=2012-12-21 \
--end=2012-12-21 \
--pipeline=db-importer \
--run-spiders
```

*NOTE: The options after the `JAR` (`--start`, `--end` etc.) are specific to my `Spark` application. I'm using [`scopt`](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) for this*

---

- I'm aware that I can supply all the various options in above `spark-submit` command using `Livy` [`POST/batches` request](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#post-batches).
- But since I have to make over 250 `spark-submit`s remotely, I'd like to exploit `Livy`'s **session-management capabilities**; i.e., I want `Livy` to create a `SparkSession` once and then use it for all my `spark-submit` requests.
- The [`POST/sessions` request](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#post-sessions) allows me to specify quite a few options for instantiating a `SparkSession` remotely. However, I see no *`session` argument* in [`POST/batches` request](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#post-batches).

How can I make use of the `SparkSession` that I created using `POST/sessions` request for submitting my `Spark` job using `POST/batches` request?

---

I've referred to following examples but they only demonstrate supplying (`python`) *code* for `Spark` job within `Livy`'s `POST` request

- [`pi_app`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/pi_app.py)
- [`rssanders3/airflow-spark-operator-plugin`](https://github.com/rssanders3/airflow-spark-operator-plugin/blob/master/example_dags/livy_spark_operator_python_example.py)
- [`livy/examples`](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/examples/)

Comment: Here's the [link](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/477d2745ffb595cf7f323691d8557058dd2048291e3eeff495522322@%3Cuser.livy.apache.org%3E) to my query to [Livy users](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?user@livy.apache.org) mailing list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make use of the `SparkSession` that I created using
>   `POST/sessions` request for submitting my `Spark` job using
>   `POST/batches` request?

- At this stage, I'm all but certain that **this is not possible** right now
- [**@Luqman Ghani**'s comment](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!msg/livy-user/TFLc7wIaQ8Y/EydZM-4HBAAJ) gives a fairly good hint that `batch`-mode is intended for different use-case than `session`-mode / `LivyClient`

---

The reason I've identified why this isn't possible is (please correct me if I'm wrong / incomplete) as follows

- `POST/batches` request accepts `JAR`
- This inhibits `SparkSession` (or `spark-shell`) from being re-used (**without restarting the `SparkSession`**) because

  - How would you remove `JAR` from previous `POST/batches` request?
  - How would you add `JAR` from current `POST/batches` request?

---

And here's a more complete picture

- Actually **[`POST/sessions`](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#post-sessions) allows you to pass a `JAR`**
- but then further interactions with that `session` (obviously) cannot take `JAR`s
- they (further interactions) can only be simple scripts (like `PySpark`: simple `python` files) that can be loaded into the `session` (and not `JAR`s)

---

Possible workaround

- All those who have their **`Spark`-application written in `Scala` / `Java`**, which must be bundled in a `JAR`, **will face this difficulty**; `Python` (`PySpark`) users are lucky here
- As a possible workaround, you can try this (i see no reason why it wouldn't work)

  - launch a `session` with your `JAR` via `POST/sessions` request
  - then invoke the *entrypoint*-`class` from your `JAR` via `python` (submit `POST /sessions/{sessionId}/statements`) as many times as you want (with *possibly* different parameters). While this wouldn't be *straight-forward*, it sounds very much possible

---

Finally I found some more alternatives to `Livy` for **remote `spark-submit`**; [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092691/3679900)