# Spark job submission using Airflow by submitting batch POST method on Livy and tracking job

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, livy

I want to use Airflow for orchestration of jobs that includes running some pig scripts, shell scripts and spark jobs.

Mainly on Spark jobs, I want to use Apache Livy but not sure whether it is good idea to use or run spark-submit.

What is best way to track Spark job using Airflow if even I submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption is you an application `JAR` containing `Java` / `Scala` code that you want to submit to remote `Spark` cluster. `Livy` is arguably the best option for **remote `spark-submit`** when evaluated against other possibilities:

- **Specifying remote `master` IP**: [Requires](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37649944/3679900) modifying *global configurations / environment variables*
- **Using `SSHOperator`**: `SSH` connection might *break*
- **Using `EmrAddStepsOperator`**: Dependent on `EMR`

---

Regarding **tracking**

- `Livy` [only reports](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#post-batches) `state` and not *progress* (% completion of stages)
- If your'e OK with that, you can just *poll* the `Livy` server via `REST` API and keep printing logs in console, those will appear on task logs in WebUI (`View Logs`)

---

Other considerations

- `Livy` [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746286/use-existing-sparksession-in-post-batches-request) reusing `SparkSession` for `POST/batches` request
- If that's imperative, you'll have to write your application code in `PySpark` and use `POST/session` requests

---

References

- [How to submit Spark jobs to EMR cluster from Airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022129)
- [`livy/examples/pi_app`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/pi_app.py)
- [`rssanders3/livy_spark_operator_python_example`](https://github.com/rssanders3/airflow-spark-operator-plugin/blob/master/example_dags/livy_spark_operator_python_example.py)

---

Useful links

- [How to submit Spark jobs to EMR cluster from Airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54022129/3679900)
- [Remote spark-submit to YARN running on EMR](https://medium.com/@tamizhgeek/remote-spark-submit-toyarn-running-on-emr-9804b89d82d2)

Comment: Thank you @y2k-shubham . My source code is in scala and want to run as Application using jar. It looks like Livy is better option and i will submit using batches with POST method. Tracking progress is problematic but I think for now tracking status should be good enough.